# How to delete message using requests library

Tags: python, discord

I need script to delete my own discord messages. Сhat id and id of the message that I previously wrote are already inserted, for some reason the message is not deleted. What's the problem?

```
    import requests as r

    s = r.Session()
    s.headers['authorization'] = input('Token: ')

    rp2 = s.delete(f'https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/******************/*******************').json()
```

Comment: What response do you get in `rp2`? Also it looks like the URL is [/channels/{channel.id}/messages/{message.id}](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#delete-message) and you seem to be using `/channels/{channel.id}/{message.id}`, is that right?

Comment: Really, the problem is that I wrote the wrong url, thanks!